# Can Magento 2 CE handle 15 million products?

Tags: magento2

What is the maximum number of products magento 2 can handle? Can magento 2 handle 15 million products?

Comment: no limit, RAM and power of your server is your actual limit!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, there is no limit. Tests have proven that Magento 2 is infinit scalable.

Comment: I have imported 15 million products. But catalog search indexing does not complete in days despite a very powerful server with 16GB ram and all the ram allocated to PHP. It just quits without giving an error or success message and catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 table remains empty and no product are shown inside categories on frontend.

Comment: 16 GB isn't enough I would recommend a lot more, maybe try 128GB.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 hasn't mentioned a product limit.
But it can handle a huge amount of products and indexing based on the server setup.

I have created 500000 products but the indexing has taken around 3 to 4 hours to complete. So we need to keep in mind the indexing when creating huge amounts of products in magento 2 CE.

below document will help to understand

Indexing: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html#indexing

Performance testing:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html

System requirements:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: I have imported 15 million products. But catalog search indexing does not complete in days despite a very powerful server with 16GB ram and all the ram allocated to PHP. It just quits without giving an error or success message and catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 table remains empty and no product are shown inside categories on frontend.

Comment: Products will be shown once indexing completed. But indexing will not complete as i experienced for 800000 products in magento 2 CE. Its considering 8000000 product as "extra large catalog' based on magento 2 "Performance testing" document